# Error "Define_NED_Function() missing from c++" trying to implement my own function in omnet++

Tags: user-defined-functions, omnet++

I'm new in Omnetpp and I am using it to study queueing with the help of inet framework.
In this I need to have a function that repeat a string n-times. I'm searching it but I'm not finding.
For this reason I'm trying to implement it in omnetpp 5.6.2. I defined it in
Omnetpp-5.6.2\src\sim\nedfunctions.cc adding this code:

```
cNedValue nedf_repeatstr(cComponent *contextComponent, cNedValue argv[], int argc) {  
std::string s = argv[0].stdstringValue();
std::string s1 = argv[0].stdstringValue();
int n = argv[1];
for (int i=1; i<n;i++) 
s += s1;
return s; } Define_NED_Function(ned_repeatstr, "string repeatstr(string s, int n)");
```

But when I play the omnepp.ini it say "define_ned_function() or define_ned_math_function() missing from c++?"

Where am I wrong?
Can some one help me?

Comment: Hi, were you able to resolve the issue?